# Showing a YouTube video in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I would like to embed a YouTube player onto a page and show it to a user. If a foreground popup is used to host the player then, when the popup loses focus, the player is destroyed because the entire popup is removed.

I was hoping to use webKitNotifications.createHTMLNotification() and embed a player inside of an HTML Notification, but the spec has since been deprecated.

Just curious if anyone has any really crafty ideas on how to achieve this? I suspect hosting the YouTube player on a background page is a violation of YouTube's Terms of Service.

Looking through the dev. channel APIs:

- http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html - Too restrictive compared to HTML Notification. Doesn't look like I can embed a YouTube player inside one of these guys.

and... that's really about it.

Advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have an HTML file in your extension for your page, for instance `video.html`, list it in your manifest under `web_accesible_resources`, and show it using:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('video.html')});
```

Inside your page you can use whatever method you want to embed the YouTube player.

Comment: That's what I'm investigating currently, but it looks like Extensions aren't allowed to hide the created tab or window. Apps seems to have that right, but the best a window can do is just be minimized. I'm looking for something that I can hide when popup closes to give the same effect as having closed, but without having the HTML removed. I'll keep playing around and report back if I find anything else cool!

Comment: @SeanAnderson That's right, you can't have a hidden window, but why do you want to hide it instead of closing it? You want it to keep playing? You want to pause and resume later?

Comment: @rsanches I would like the video to keep playing. I currently embed the YouTube iframe onto a background page. This allows the audio to continue playing. I pipe the video to the foreground like so: http://bit.ly/19xb9uY but it is a horrible workaround introducing complicated bugs. I'm looking for a more elegant solution where the page would be sometimes visible in the foreground and sometimes invisible.