# Embedding YouTube video in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I would like to embed a video hosted on YouTube and play it when the user clicks on a button in popup.html.

I was following the solution listed here:

[Showing a YouTube video in a Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990317/showing-a-youtube-video-in-a-google-chrome-extension)

A new tab opens but I don't see the video, I only see a gray rectangle with a smiley inside.

I guess Google is blocking the video somehow.
Is it possible to show YouTube video on a new tab opened by background.js?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX?html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
```

Comment: This depends on how you're doing the embedding. Show us your code of the page that contains the video

Comment: I'm using the bootstrap platform and I edited the OP with  how I embed the video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a protocol-relative URL:

```
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX?html5=1"
```

At the same time, the embedding page has a URL like

```
chrome-extension://yourextensionidhere/page.html
```

This results in an `src` URL

```
chrome-extension://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX?html5=1
```

which is obviously invalid and results in a network error (rendered in a subframe as a grey page with a sad face).

To resolve this, change the protocol-relative URL to explicit `https://...`