# play instagram video fetched from public api

Tags: vue.js, video, instagram

I've searched a bit here on SO to find a way to show instagram video using the public api `?__a=1` method. I've found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701957/how-to-get-video-from-instagram-public-access-api) that have pointed me into the right direction but not at all.

after I get the user media, I'm checking in my vue app if the resource is a video or an image and if is a video I show an html5 player where I'm binding the url that is obtained form the public json api. What I'm facing is that the player will not reproduce the video, but if I use the url into the browser, an html5 player is loaded with the related video that will start playing.
The video urls returned are something like this one:

`"https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-16/117420353_635186773777278_7723572524374891239_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=nI6tYDeag-0AX8MtmoL&oe=5F3C077B&oh=a47046b1aabf223f16c4c66526e20e57"`

I've tried to remove all the part after the `.mp4` file extension but this will not work, so I suspect that all the url is needed. Is there a way that I can use to reproduce video in my app?

Comment: Do you have a basic demo page (link) showing the problem in action?

Answer (score 1):

After many tryes unfortunately I didn't figured out how to use my own HTML5 player so I've used a simple solution. An `<iframe>` with the url set will let the vido play into the app, this exclude me from the ability to remove the download button or controls from the player but at the moment it's the only way I can implement to achieve my scope.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Your link works okay for me in a video tag:

```
<video width="640" height="480" >

<source src="https://scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-16/117420353_635186773777278_7723572524374891239_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=nI6tYDeag-0AX8MtmoL&oe=5F3C077B&oh=a47046b1aabf223f16c4c66526e20e57" 

type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

**(2)** It even works okay in this [**random demo**](https://codepen.io/ykob/pen/jBjVEY) that uses `vue.js`.

With no demo page of your problem the solution is a guess...

- Make sure that your own site URL starts `https://` or else change the video `src` to `http://...etc`.
- Make sure your server (*settings?*) isn't somehow blocking you from loading the file.
- If still failing, show us the problem via some link to your testing page.

Comment: I'm not calling the url from a website but from a chrome extension

Comment: That's a new detail that wasn't obvious in your Question. Are you making the extension yourself or asking about playing video in some previously downloaded one? If you're making then you could also try first making an HTML file that contains a `<video>` tag and secondly proceed to [load that file into your extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991610/2057709)

Comment: I'm writing the code. I think the problem can be that I didn't added the instagram cdn host to manifest file, I need to try after I add the host

Comment: Okay. If you find a good solution then [**update your answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63440840/edit) cos it might help others in future.